# Problems and trignometric generalities

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, geometry

I am practicing physics questions by doing David Morin exercises on classical mechanics. However, I don't understand a particularity of the solution to this problem,

[image]

and I think that it's not limited to this problem. Basically in this specific problem is mentions that $v_y = v\cdot cos\theta$ because the initial velocity makes an angle of $(90º-\theta)$ degrees with respect to the horizontal. I understood the rest of the problem, and the concepts underlying them, however I dont know how they make the deduction of the angle. I know this may be some simple problem, but I don't understand it and in my class (as in majority of physics classes) the teacher basically ignores this trignometric identities. My question is, how can we make this trignometric relations, generalizing to other problems? How can one practice this? I know some of them by memorizing and visualization, like the classic cases of a block on inclined plane, projectile motion etc. but when it's new scenarios I mess up easily this situations.

Comment: Might want to crop the image to make it legible.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Draw a triangle in the diagram to find out when you need to use $\sin$ or $\cos$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by noticing that the angle between the tangential velocity vector and the vertical increases as θ increases.  This is a quick way to tell if two angles are equal.  Then the component of a vector which is adjacent to a known angle is found using a cosine. With this problem, keep in mind that the starting height (at which the mud comes loose) also changes as the vertical component of the velocity changes.

Answer (score 1):

$\vec v$ is perpendicular to the vector $\vec R$ from the center to the point where v is indicated.  The vertical component of $\vec v$ is perpendicular to the horizontal line from the center to the circle.  Therefore, the angle between $\vec v$ and $v_y$ is $\theta$ and $v_y = v \enspace cos(\theta)$.

Look at what happens when the angle changes. Draw out the vertical and horizontal components of $\vec v$ on the above diagram. When $\theta$ goes to zero $v_y$ goes to $v$, and when $\theta$ goes to 90 degrees $v_y$ goes to zero, indicating the angle between $\vec v$ and its vertical component is $\theta$.

Many physics books assume a rather good knowledge of trigonometry.  Suggest you look at some engineering textbooks on statics and dynamics that tend to have more worked-out examples than some physics texts.  Also, there are numerous aids on line.